# local html/css/javascript project into UWP app - images not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uwp

Bit of a Javasctipt noob any help appreciated.

I've been asked to transfer a local webapp to a uwp app. 
I've got almost everything working publishing in debug from VS into a JS UWP. 
However some of the images don't show and I get the black X boxes where they should be.

From content.js this what's the

```
"Image":"images/Image-left.jpg",
```

I'm figuring there's somewhere I have to set the source - and other images that have been set with a source are showing appropriately. I just don't know where to look to know where to hook it up.

```
<img src=\"images/JR-Email-Signature.png\"
```

The images are all held inside the "images" folder in the solution, they are all named correctly.

I've tried fiddling with image properties so they copy to ouput directory but this didn't make any difference.

Thanks in advance. 
Cam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I left a really important piece out for @Sunteen - sorry such a JS Noob. 
The app was created in Angularjs so it was using `ng-src` to pull through the images - and adding your changes above didn't work. Thanks for the help though!

When debugging and running developer mode over the top I found that my images in the output were getting `unsafe:ms-appx-web:///images/Image-left.jpg`

I ended up talking to a friend and after a few more googles we found that we needed to add exceptions for images in UWP for Jscript images.

So we added these lines of code to app.js in .

```
rmeApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx-web|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx-web|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
}]);
```

Note that there were other solutions around that listed the above - however they only had `ms-appx` in the code rather than `ms-appx-web`

After popping those in it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> The images are all held inside the "images" folder in the solution

If they are inside "images" folder in the solution， directly set the image relative path to the `src` property will work well. But don't use backslash in your path or it will show a black X.

```
<img src="images/download.jpg" />
```

For images in "Application install directory" or "Application data locations", using Uri also will work well on a UWP javacript app. For example, install directory:

```
<img src="ms-appx:///images/download.jpg" />
```

Local folder:

```
<img src="ms-appdata:///local/caffe3.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sunteen -  however this does not work. I think part of the problem is that this code is held within content.js - I don't fully understand this - but my research suggest this is a DOM? and UWP doesn't handle DOM yet???

Comment: Sorry just to add a little more context... my code above is in content.js and the code is held within {...} so the <img src=\"images/JR-Email-Signature.png\" is actually within {....<img src=\"images/JR-Email-Signature.png\"....}

Comment: @Tilcey what project template did you create? What is your `content.js`? Please provide your full code of `content.js` or please a [mcve] project provide. The code above can work well on my side.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I've found a solution and will post soon.